# Only some glyphicons showing in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Me and my colleague have been trying to solve this problem for awhile and we can not get it to work. Hopefully someone out there is smarter than us and have some good input on this.

When using IE8, IE9 or IE10 to visit websites http://glyphicons.com/ or http://getbootstrap.com/components/ not all the glyphicons are showing (some are showing but others just show as boxes []).

In Chrome all are showing.

EDIT: I should add that this is on computers on our company network. Could there be a setting here that prevents us for show all glyphicons?

EDIT2: I now have suspicions that our Group Policy disables XMLHTTP for all users on network. Therefore, is it possible to encode the halfling font and use it directly in the CSS?

Comment: I'm able see all of them in IE10 and 9.   Not sure, if this the cause for the problem "check the document mode in IE browser"

Comment: When using dev-mode I can see that IE8-standards are used as document mode.

Comment: I have noticed that when going to Glyphicons.com I get 420+ icons on IE8 and 470+ icons on IE9, why? Could this be part of the solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the solution. It was quite simple. Unfortunately I won't be able to use Glyphicons.

IE have a setting to restrict font download. This is enabled by group policy and cannot be changed on standard workstations. I have been able to recreate the same behavior on my own laptop by restricting font download.

Se this article for further explanation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533034(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment olahell, if you count icons you will get 470 icons although it's write 420 with IE8. It's maybe an old forgotten image only shown on old IE version.

Comment: Thank you. That could be it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Glyphicons site does some browser sniffing to come up with the 470 / 420 icon figure. The most likely reason for that is that 50 icons dont work in IE; and that is probably due to IE having no SVG support.