# Glyphicon shopping cart not working in Internet Explorer 7 (IE7)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, glyphicons

In Internet Explorer 7 the `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>` doesn't work.

How to get this working?

Comment: Bootstrap v3 doesn't support IE7.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your css. See https://github.com/yargalot/glyphicons-bootstrap3-ie7 for more information about this solution.

```
.glyphicon {
     font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
     font-style: normal;
     text-decoration: inherit;
     line-height: normal;
 }


.glyphicon-shopping-cart {
   zoom: expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '&#xe116;');
}
```

You problem could also lie in the security settings of the browser. See [Only some glyphicons showing in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026479/only-some-glyphicons-showing-in-ie) and [bootstrap 3.2.0 glyphicons are not displaying in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281286/bootstrap-3-2-0-glyphicons-are-not-displaying-in-internet-explorer)

Hope that helps