# IE not displaying glyphicons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, glyphicons

I have the following code:

```
 if ( $value['customized'] == true) {
    echo("<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true'></span>&nbsp;</td>");
} else{
     echo("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
} //end if
```

which renders this html:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>PStatus</th>
         <th>Customized</th>
         <th>DS</th>
         <th>T Name</th>
         <th>Audit Date</th>
         <th>ObjectID</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success"></button></td>
         <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
         <td>ll-ci1</td>
         <td><a href="location_details.php?loc=ll">ll-ci1</a></td>
         <td>July 29 2016 13:54:12</td>
         <td>579b994a3747106e60a089e1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"></button></td>
         <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
         <td>lw1</td>
         <td><a href="location_details.php?loc=lw1">lw1</a></td>
         <td>July 29 2016 14:09:51</td>
         <td>579b9ab63747106e60a089e2</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

In IE, the glyphicon-ok icon doesn't show up. 
Instead I get an error message that says I have an unmatched end tag. 
The line it's complaining about is this one:

```
 <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success"></button></td>
```

And it's got the "" item highlighted.
i can't see where i've gone wrong... 
I think I need another set of eyes, if anyone wants to take a look.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

For now, I've changed this:

```
   <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
```

to this:

```
   <td><span class='badge'>Yes</span></td>
```

Comment: I tested ur code in IE, and chrome. It works fine. Try hitting ctrl + F5

Comment: strange. i cleared cache and history.  closed browser and restarted.  still missing the glyphs.  also did CTRL + F5

Comment: found this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026479/only-some-glyphicons-showing-in-ie.  Might be related.  Checking it out

Comment: Does there happen to be a some sort of zero width character in the string that can not be seen? Try to delete the line and retype and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: U can try using Font Awesome

Comment: @epascarello checking...gonna save the rendered page to a .html file and then try just playing around with that...

Comment: I couldn't get it working.  In the interests of meeting my deadline, i'm going to have to just make a work around.  Please see edit 1